# Como agregar un elemento a ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Hola Buenas tardes acudo porque tengo una duda si me pudieran ayudar.

Deseo crear un `ArrayList` de una clase,tener un arreglo dinámico de objetos de una clase, lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
  ArrayList<Persona> pruebas = new ArrayList();
  pruebas.set(0, new Persona());                                 
  System.out.println(pruebas.get(0).getNombre());
```

pero me lanza un error de ejecución:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:
>   0, Size: 0

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me pueden ayudar por favor.

Comment: Antes que todo, por favor no pegues una imagen de tu codigo. Pega efectivamente tu codigo.

Comment: Las imágenes, no sólo hacen imposible copiar tu código para probarlo, sino que también pueden ser difíciles de leer (pensemos en celulares que no definan bien la imagen o en personas con problemas de vista). ¿Podrías por favor incluir el código y el mensaje de error como texto? Encontrarás el enlace para **[edit]** debajo de tu pregunta. Luego de pegarlo, hay que seleccionar el código completamente y hacer click en el botón `{  }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te marca ese error por que no tienes ningún elemento en tu lista

Primero debes agregar elementos de la siguiente manera:

```
personas.add(new Presona());
```

Y si vas a reemplazar ese elemento ahora si haces teniendo ya elementos en tu lista:

```
personas.set(0, new Presona());
```

[Ejemplo](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-arraylist-set-method-example/)

Answer (score 3):

Primero y principal, la clase arraylist esta explicada en manuales a traves de toda la web.

Por ejemplo, [aca](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_arraylist.htm)

Dicho esto, el metodo set, tiene como firma:

> E set(int index, E element)
>
> This method replaces the element at the specified position in this
>   list with the specified element.

Que quiere decir que se usa para reemplazar un elemento existente en la lista. Cosa que aca no es lo que queres hacer, si no que queres agregar.

Para agregar elementos, se usa el metodo

> boolean add(E e)
>
> This method appends the specified element to the end of this list.

Este metodo agrega un elemento al final de la lista. Como esta lista no tiene elementos, esto es justamente lo que querias hacer. por lo tanto, tu codigo deberia ser:

```
pruebas.add(new persona());
```

Answer (score 2):

Como puedes ver tu arreglo no tiene definido un indice 0 , como vez en la Exepcion que dice index : 0 size 0 que significa que no tiene definido nada de eso

por el contrario podrias utlizar ,

```
personas.add(new Presona());
```

Answer (score 1):

El error:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

es debido a que tratas de obtener la información de un objeto en el indice 0 de tu `ArrayList` el cual en realidad no existe.

El método que debes usar para introducir un elemento a tu `ArrayList` es [**add()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-).

> [**add()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-): Inserta el elemento especificado en la posición
>   especificada en esta lista. Cambia el elemento actualmente en esa
>   posición (si existe) y cualquier elemento posterior a la derecha
>   (agrega uno a sus índices).

Ya que el método

> **[set()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-)** reemplaza el elemento en la posición especificada en esta lista con el elemento especificado.

**[set()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-)**, reemplaza pero no inserta, por lo tanto insertar elementos usa el método **[set()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-)** :

```
 ArrayList<Persona> pruebas = new ArrayList();
      //pruebas.set(0, new Persona());
      pruebas.add(0, new Persona());
```